# Fixing memory leak with temporary data table (heap vs stack)

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I have a snippet of code that is used to populate a table. It opens a file on disk and throws the data into a table.

```
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
      QDataStream stream(&file);
      qint32 numRows, numColumns;
      stream >> numRows >> numColumns;
      QStandardItemModel* tempModel = new QStandardItemModel;
      tempModel->setRowCount(numRows);
      tempModel->setColumnCount(numColumns);

      for (int i = 0; i < numRows ; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
          QStandardItem* tempItem = new QStandardItem; // stored in heap
          tempItem->read(stream);
          tempModel->setItem(i, j, tempItem);
        }
      }
      file.close();
      tableView->setModel(tempModel);
      ...
    }
```

This code works. But the issue I'm having is that, the more files I open, the more memory is being used and it never goes down. If I add a second file, for example, I don't need to store the previous file's model anymore. I want to delete it.

I'm guessing the memory is not being freed up because it never gets deleted since I'm using the `new` keyword and a pointer.

If we take the `tempItem` `for` loop as an example, I imagine I'd have to do something similar to this to fix it:

```
      for (int i = 0; i < numRows ; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
          //QStandardItem* tempItem = new QStandardItem;
          QStandardItem tempItem; // store on stack and delete at end of scope
          //tempItem->read(stream);
          tempItem.read(stream);
          tempModel->setItem(i, j, tempItem);
        }
```

But even then, it throws an error because `QStandardItemModel`'s `setItem` (seen [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setItem)) takes a `QStandardItem` pointer.

I'd like to fix this for both `tempModel` and `tempItem` if possible. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: set a parent for your model, so that it gets destroyed when it should...

Comment: The first example is correct, As per the documentation tempModel->setItem() takes the ownership of tempItem. You need to delete tempModel once the work is done, then it should work fine

Comment: Thank you @DakshGupta. I'm just not sure when I should be deleting it. If I put `delete tempModel` right under `tableView->setModel(tempModel);`, the table shows up empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up setting a single `QStandardItemModel` in my header file and my main window's initialization list.

**myapp.h**

```
...
  QStandardItemModel* mainModel;
...
```

**myapp.cpp**

```
...
MyApp::MyApp(QWidget* parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent),
    mainModel(new QStandardItemModel(tableView)),
...
```

I changed the way the application works so that I only ever need one model for my table view. Whenever I need to add a new data set to populate the table with, I clear the current table entirely, create a new, temporary model, then set the temp model to the main model.

```
mainTableModel->clear();
QStandardItemModel* tempModel = new QStandardItemModel;
tempModel->setRowCount(numRows);
tempModel->setColumnCount(numColumns);

for (int i = 0; i < numRows ; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
    QStandardItem* tempItem = new QStandardItem();
    tempItem->read(stream);
    tempModel->setItem(i, j, tempItem);
  }
}

file.close();    
mainModel = tempModel;    
tableView->setModel(mainModel);
```

Clearing the model and reusing it lessens, but does not fix, the memory leak.

Comment: you are still leaking old `mainModel` objects. When you assign the `mainModel` pointer to the newly created `tempModel`, you aren't deleting the old object. Although, these models are empty as they don't contain any `QStandardItemModel`s (since you are `clear`ing them), but they do still count as a memory leak, you can run a memory debugger and detect them yourself ;)

Comment: The only good thing you have done here, is that you are now creating the model as a child of the `MyApp` object. Just clear the old model, and re-populate. That is less code, better design, straight to the point, no coronaries...

Answer (score 1):

The memory leak is not due to `QStandardItem` ownership. The `setItem()` method takes ownership of the `QStandardItem` objects, which will be freed automatically when the `QStandardItemModel` object is freed.

Your memory leak is due to the `tableView->setModel(tempModel);`statement, because that method **does not** take ownership. When you change the model, or free the view, you are responsible for freeing the model.

See [this document](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setModel) for details.

For example:

```
QItemSelectionModel *m = tableView->selectionModel();
tableView->setModel(tempModel);
delete m;
```

Comment: Thank you. At what point should I do the `delete tempModel`, though? If I put it right after `tableView->setModel(tempModel);`, the table doesn't get populated. (also, maybe I'm missing something, but should i even be concerned with selection models in this instance?)

Comment: You don't delete `tempModel` until `tableView` is deleted or a new model is set using `setModel()`. The value `m` is the previous `tempModel` that is no longer needed and therefore safe to delete.